# How to stop "TCP Transport Error" and "Connection Refused" in MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

I'm trying to build Nexus Mod Manager in MonoDevelop. After a random interval, it stops building or even *cleaning*. The first thing I get is "TCP Transport error", and then every other time "Connection Refused". (ie: "Clean failed. Connection refused")

Is that part of MonoDevelop? Or is this the result of some command specific to the project I am building? I ask because it is a difficult question to search for answers. I'm not very familiar with MonoDevelop, so I don't even know where to look to see what is causing that.

It would also be great to know if MonoDevelop stores a build-log somewhere, or if that, too, is up to the project.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what version of Mono and MonoDevelop are you using?

Comment: MonoDevelop: 4.2.3, Mono: 3.2.3-1; on arch, MonoDevelop is from aur/git.

Comment: it's possible that your problem is fixed by this commit: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/bbd4ee4181787189fbb1f8ba6364afdd982ae706 (which is only in master, so either you build Mono from master, or wait for version 3.2.7 to be tagged by Mono team, and later packaged by Arch)

Comment: That could be it. I guess I will keep waiting for 3.2.7. If you don't mind me asking, what is monodev doing? Where is it connecting? Why does it need to connect to anything at all? I could find any way to pm, sorry for cluttering comments.

Comment: monodevelop uses remoting internally to communicate between its different processes (i.e.: the process that calls the compiler), and remoting uses sockets

Comment: Alright, thanks. I didn't know if it was some kind of custom buildstep in the project instead of the IDE.